# Is it possible and meaningful to execute an Array DML command containing BLOB data?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, dml, anydac, firedac

Is it possible to execute an Array DML `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement passing a BLOB field data in the parameter array ? And the more important part of my question, if it is possible, will Array DML command containing BLOB data still be more efficient than executing commands one by one ?

I have noticed that `TADParam` has a `AsBlobs` indexed property so I assume it might be possible, but I haven't tried this yet because there's no mention of performance nor example showing this and because the indexed property is of type `RawByteString` which is not much suitable for my needs.

I'm using FireDAC and working with SQLite database (`Params.BindMode = pbByNumber`, so I'm using native SQLite `INSERT` with multiple `VALUES`). My aim is to store about 100k records containing pretty small BLOB data (about 1kB per record) as fast as possible (in cost of the FireDAC's abstraction).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main point in your case is that you are using a `SQLIte3` database.

With `SQLite3`, Array DML is "emulated" by FireDAC. Since it is a *local instance*, not a client-server instance, there is no need to prepare a bunch of rows, then send them at once to avoid network latency (as with Oracle or MS SQL).

Using Array DML *may* speed up your insertion process a little bit with SQLite3, but I doubt it will very high. Good plain INSERT with binding per number will work just fine.

The main tips about performance in your case will be:

- Nest your process within a single transaction (or even better, use one transaction per 1000 rows of data);
- Prepare an INSERT statement, then re-execute it with a bound parameter each time;
- By default, FireDAC initialize SQLite3 with the fastest options (e.g. disabling LOCK), so let it be.

SQlite3 is very good about BLOB process.

[From my tests](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/06/16/FireDAC-/-AnyDAC-support-for-mORMot), FireDAC insertion timing is pretty good, very close to direct SQlite3 access. Only reading is slower than a direct SQLite3 link, due to the overhead of the Delphi `TDataSet` class.